# How to do concatenation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to do concatenation in SQL Server?

I wrote below query and its return always null value. I want to execute if condition for data exists or not

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT con.ID, BusinessName, FirstName, LastName, con.MobileNo, TelephoneNo,con.Email AS Email, 
            Address1,  ISNULL(con.IsActive,0) AS IsActive, ISNULL(Status,0)AS Status, st.Name AS StatusName, ISNULL(st.ColorID,0)AS ColorID,
            (SELECT TOP 1 cfu.Remark FROM CRM_ContactFollowUp cfu WHERE cfu.ContactID = con.ID ORDER BY ID DESC) AS Remark, con.CreatedBy, 
            emp.Name AS CreatedName,con.CreatedOn, con.DueDate
            FROM CRM_Contacts con
            LEFT JOIN CRM_Status st ON st.ID = con.Status
            LEFT JOIN PMS_Employee emp ON emp.ID=con.CreatedBy
            WHERE con.OrganizationID='+ Convert(Varchar,@OrganizationID)+' AND('+@WhereClause +') ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET ('+ Convert(Varchar,@PageIndex) +')
            ROWS FETCH NEXT '+ Convert(Varchar,@PageSize) +' ROWS ONLY';

            SET @NextQuery ='IF(EXISTS (SELECT con.ID FROM CRM_Contacts con WHERE con.OrganizationID= '+ Convert(Varchar,@OrganizationID)+' AND 
             ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET ('+ Convert(Varchar,@NextPage) +') ROWS FETCH NEXT '+ Convert(Varchar,@PageSize) +' ROWS ONLY) )
                SET '+ Convert(Varchar,@IsMoreRecords)+'= 1 
            ELSE
                SET '+ Convert(Varchar,@IsMoreRecords)+'= 0';

            EXEC(@Query);
            EXEC(@NextQuery);
```

Here is my complete procedure https://jsfiddle.net/npathak56/aLsngae5/

@Query execute properly but @NextQuery not Executed Why?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.   You might also explain what you are trying to do.  The query makes no sense.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s I am using SP but here I posted only query because SP is too lengthy

Answer (score 0):

I did not run your procedure, as it is too complex to replicate locally, but I don't like this statement:

```
SET '+ Convert(Varchar,@IsMoreRecords)+'= 1
```

In my opinion it should be

```
SET @IsMoreRecords = 1
```

You want to assign an output variable, but you are using its value.
And, of course, so for the second similar statement.

```
SET @IsMoreRecords = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your most basic problem is that you can't concatenate strings that have single quotes inside them using that method.  SQL will interpret those single quotes as part of the concatenation function instead of part of the string.  So if you do:

```
SET @Query = 'SELECT [field] from [table] 
              where [field] like '%%whatevs%%' 
              and [field2] like ' + @var
```

You can see just with the Stack Overflow syntax highlighting that `%%whatevs%%` ends up outside the string because `like` uses single quotes.  So your query will never work when written like that.